# ORA-01652: unable to extend temp segment by 128 in tablespace TEMP - is this recoverable?

Tags: oracle

I have a table that has 188307430 records.
It also has partitions.

above two statements I realized after firing a SELECT on the table

```
select * from emp order by created_date;
```

This caused the above exception related to temp segment in TEMP tablespace.
So I have multiple questions:
Is this issue recoverable - i.e will all other users get impacted ?
or will other selects simply cause Oracle to cleanup the TEMP tablespace ?

Answer (score 0):

> #### 01652, 00000, "unable to extend temp segment by %s in tablespace %s"
>
> **Cause:**  Failed to allocate an extent of the required number of blocks for
>             a temporary segment in the tablespace indicated.
>
> **Action:** Use ALTER TABLESPACE ADD DATAFILE statement to add one or more
>             files to the tablespace indicated.

Yes this recoverable. In Oracle database SMON process is responsible to clean temp segments that are no longer needed.

> will all other users get impacted ?

Yes, If their SQLs need TEMP segments then they are also impacted.

Comment: can you please elaborate why other users will be impacted - IF - smon process would clean the temp segments ?

Comment: @satishmarathe:  If SMON couldn't find the temp segment to clean up, all are being used by Oracle processes then? You need extra space for new users.

Comment: @satishmarathe: Also check whether your temp file is auto extensible or not.